# Spring cloud Kafka Stream:Error creating bean with name 'kafkaMessageChannelBinder'

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, kafka-producer-api

I'm trying to use the spring cloud Kafka streams binder(2.4.3) to consume and produce Avro messages. I'm able to consume the message and produce the records with a single function but **I'm looking for a producer which I can use multiple times in the application**. StreamBridge seems like an option for this and tried the below approach but it does not work, Did I missed anything

```
    @Autowired
    StreamBridge streamBridge;

    @Bean
    public Consumer<KStream<EventKey, Event>> process(){
        return input -> {
             input.peek((k,v) -> sendToValue(v)
              );
        };
    }


    private Event sendToValue(Event event){
        System.out.println(Event);
        streamBridge.send("process-out-0",event);
        System.out.println("Message sent");
        return touchpointEvent;
    }
```

Binder:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: ${applicaton-name}
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: process
      bindings:
        process-in-0:
          destination: ${input-topic-name}
          contentType: application/Avro
        process-out-0:
          destination: ${enriched-topic-name}
          contentType: application/Avro
      binding-retry-interval: 30
      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            brokers: ${kafka-broker}
            application-id: ${consumer-group-name}
            auto-create-topics: false
            auto-add-partitions: false
            configuration:
              processing.guarantee: at_least_once
              auto.offset.reset: earliest
              schema.registry.url: ${kafka-schema-registry}
              auto-register-schema: false
              security.protocol: SSL
              useNativeEncoding: true
              specific.avro.reader: true
```

Error

```
[2021-03-16 21:51:52,219] [INFO] [latest-c8b6dd0c-b376-4cdd-a72d-17e97701d1d5-StreamThread-1] [o.s.c.s.b.DefaultBinderFactory DefaultBinderFactory.java:243] Creating binder: ktable
[2021-03-16 21:51:52,312] [INFO] [latest-c8b6dd0c-b376-4cdd-a72d-17e97701d1d5-StreamThread-1] [o.s.c.s.b.DefaultBinderFactory DefaultBinderFactory.java:343] Caching the binder: ktable
[2021-03-16 21:51:52,313] [INFO] [latest-c8b6dd0c-b376-4cdd-a72d-17e97701d1d5-StreamThread-1] [o.s.c.s.b.DefaultBinderFactory DefaultBinderFactory.java:347] Retrieving cached binder: ktable
[2021-03-16 21:51:52,313] [INFO] [latest-c8b6dd0c-b376-4cdd-a72d-17e97701d1d5-StreamThread-1] [o.s.c.s.b.DefaultBinderFactory DefaultBinderFactory.java:243] Creating binder: kafka
[2021-03-16 21:51:52,372] [WARN] [latest-c8b6dd0c-b376-4cdd-a72d-17e97701d1d5-StreamThread-1] [o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext AbstractApplicationContext.java:559] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaMessageChannelBinder' defined in org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.config.KafkaBinderConfiguration: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/integration/support/management/ManageableLifecycle
[2021-03-16 21:51:52,374] [INFO] [latest-c8b6dd0c-b376-4cdd-a72d-17e97701d1d5-StreamThread-1] [o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener.java:136] 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2021-03-16 21:51:52,379] [ERROR] [latest-c8b6dd0c-b376-4cdd-a72d-17e97701d1d5-StreamThread-1] [o.s.b.SpringApplication SpringApplication.java:837] Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaMessageChannelBinder' defined in org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.config.KafkaBinderConfiguration: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/integration/support/management/ManageableLifecycle
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
```

update with a version change:

```
[2021-03-17 09:56:28,043] [INFO] [latest-0ea7c0a5-21a4-464b-bf42-a5c35b6687dc-StreamThread-1] [o.a.k.c.u.AppInfoParser AppInfoParser.java:117] Kafka version: 6.0.1-ccs
[2021-03-17 09:56:28,043] [INFO] [latest-0ea7c0a5-21a4-464b-bf42-a5c35b6687dc-StreamThread-1] [o.a.k.c.u.AppInfoParser AppInfoParser.java:118] Kafka commitId: 9c1fbb3db1e0d69d
[2021-03-17 09:56:28,043] [INFO] [latest-0ea7c0a5-21a4-464b-bf42-a5c35b6687dc-StreamThread-1] [o.a.k.c.u.AppInfoParser AppInfoParser.java:119] Kafka startTimeMs: 1615992988043
[2021-03-17 09:56:28,047] [WARN] [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-2] [o.a.k.c.NetworkClient NetworkClient.java:757] [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-2] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[2021-03-17 09:56:28,151] [WARN] [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-2] [o.a.k.c.NetworkClient NetworkClient.java:757] [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-2] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[2021-03-17 09:56:28,357] [WARN] [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-2] [o.a.k.c.NetworkClient NetworkClient.java:757] [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-2] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[2021-03-17 09:56:28,568] [WARN] [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-2] [o.a.k.c.NetworkClient NetworkClient.java:757] [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-2] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[2021-03-17 09:56:28,987] [WARN] [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-2] [o.a.k.c.NetworkClient NetworkClient.java:757] [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-2] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

Comment: Looks like some dependency issues. I suspect that by 2.4.3, you mean the boot version. What version of binder? Can you show the dependencies in the maven pom?

Comment: @sobychacko Yes seems like a dependency issue for the error. but after upgrading the binder version to 3.1.1. the producer is trying to connect to localhost instead of binder configuration broker. updated the question with new logs

Answer (score 1):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/integration/support/management/ManageableLifecycle

You have an older version of `spring-integration-core` on the class path - that class was added in 5.4.

When using Boot, you should never declare versions; let Boot bring in the right version using its dependency management feature.

Comment: Yes seems like a dependency issue for the error after making changes, the producer is trying to connect to localhost instead of binder configuration broker. updated the question with new logs.

Comment: Can you try adding `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers` too? since you have `StreamBridge` which is using the regular binder. If you are adding this, I don't think you need the streams binder one (kafka.stream.binder.brokers).